# Need to convert .TLD file to CSV

Tags: php, csv, strcmp, spring-tld

I have been provided with a .TLD file . It contains categories data for my products( they are in thousands). The problem is I need to convert it to CSV but I cannot find anything online that can do it. I tried using Excel but it converts the category ID into Exponential format. Also I need to write a code to do this. There are simply no Examples to do this (.TLD to .CSV)

Interestingly, php reads my .TLD file as a normal file. Which I tried in the following code

```
<?PHP
$file_handle = fopen("PG.TLD", "rb");
$line = 0;
while ( ( $row = fgetcsv($file_handle) ) !== false ) {
if ($line <=0) {
    // Skip headers
    $line++;
    continue;
}
if($line >0){
    $texts = implode(',', $row);
    echo serialize($texts);
 }
}
fclose($file_handle);
?>
```

It uses the implode function but does not use "," anywhere. Here is the output of the above code
    http://toorakcomputerservices.com.au/tldtesting.php
I need to basically read the category ID from one file and match it with the category ID in .TLD file to get the correct Category Name. Here is the sample.TLD file

ProductGroupCode    Description ProductGroupLevel
1000    Computers   1
1001    Power & Rack Equipment  1
1002    Storage 1
1003    Displays    1
1004    Communications  1
1005    Networking  1
1004128 Video & Audio Conferencing Equipment    2
1004403 Voice Over IP (VOIP)    2
1005129 Network Interface Cards 2
1005130 Wireless Networking 2
1005140 Switches & Hubs 2
1005129001154   Phone/Power Line NICS   3
1005129001155   Token Ring NICs 3
1005130001156   Antennas & Amplifiers   3
1005130001157   Wireless Access Points (AP) 3
1005130001158   Wireless Bridges    3
1005130001159   Wireless Cabling & Components   3

In this file My search is supposed to be like this,
If ProductGroupCode is **1005130001156** than get description **Antennas & Amplifiers**

Comment: Read documentation well @shrilekha http://in2.php.net/fgetcsv here this function accept third parameter as delimiter in that pass space instead of default value comma

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I passed " " (space) in the third delimiter, It is showing , in between my category descriptions instead of columns. I must be doing something wrong clearly. http://toorakcomputerservices.com.au/tldtesting.php .              s:29:"1001 Power,&,Rack,Equipment 1";

Comment: Gotcha "Power & Rack Equipment" in this string itself it has space. So it consider everything as separate token delimited by space. So ask the data provider to put comma in between the ProductGroupCode, Description, ProductGroupLevel are else ask them itself how can I parse it if the string it self has same symbol as delimiter i.e. space. And ask them to replace space delimited to either comma or pipe separated value.

Comment: If they didn't give in csv or pipe separated value confirm them pattern of the ProductGroupCode, Description, ProductGroupLevel and make use of regular expression try to token the string

Comment: Hmm. It's bit difficult to get hold to the Person in charge of the files to change the files type as they are in a different area and department but i will still give it a shot. Thanks